# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/support/SerializationUtils

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-batch

Has anyone come across `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/support/SerializationUtils` while running spring batch Ivy project in Intellij.

It was working OK for me until I reimported my project into a separate workspace, at which point this issue appeared. I'm not clear what has to be done with the classpath or any of the other configuration options in IntelliJ. For the past day, I've been battling.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/support/SerializationUtils
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao.copy(MapJobExecutionDao.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao.saveJobExecution(MapJobExecutionDao.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:124)
    at com.rbccm.lrma.batch.jobRunner.JobTempRunner.main(JobTempRunner.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.support.SerializationUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 20 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Which version of Spring Batch do you use? This class seems absent from the v4.